# Modify user information

Tags: php, mysql

I can't modify my user information. When I click on Save, it reloads the page but it doesn't save it as new user information. I don't know if it's the SQL Injection the problem or something else. Here is a picture of how my modify page is looking: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMWMi.jpg

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Modify user</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
<?php
    $get=$_GET['id'];
    $form = "edituser.php?id=$get";
?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Modify user</h2>
    <form action="modifyuser.php" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Name / Vorname:
          </td><br>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="input_name"
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input_name'])) {
    echo 'value="'.$_POST['input_name'].'"';
}
?>
            >
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table><br>

<?php
include "config.php";
if((isset($_POST['input_add']))&&($_POST['input_name']!="")){
    if (isset($_GET['modify'])) {
        $addusername = $_POST['input_name'];
        $id = $_GET['modify'];
        $modify_query = 'update benutzer 
                            set username="'.$addusername.'" 
                            where id="'.$id.'"';
        if($link->query($modify_query)=== TRUE){
            echo "User was successfully updated";
        }else {
            echo "Error updating the user";
        }
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $modify_query);
    echo $modify_query;
    header("Location: pannel.php");
}

echo "<button class='btn btn-success' name='input_add' onclick='return confirm(\"Do you want to modify the user?\")';>Save</button>";
echo "&nbsp;";
echo "<a href='pannel.php' class='btn btn-default'>Go Back</a>";
?>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is definitely vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Is the script you show us called `modifyuser.php`?

Comment: Pretty sure I have seen this question pretty much as it is about a couple of hours ago.

Comment: You do this `$form = "edituser.php?id=$get";` but never use it?

Comment: If you want to use that then you have to use it to modify the `<form action="modifyuser.php" method="post">` line of HTML

Comment: Yeah it's modifyuser.php forgot to change it @RiggsFolly

Comment: You are still trying to access a $_GET value when POSTing the form or $_POST values assuming you actually launch this using a GET and fill the $_GET array (which will NOT put anything in the $_POST array)

Answer (score 0):

You code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Use PDO as explained below. However, for now, modify the SQL query as per your own driver. Rest would be same.

Now, try to understand the code below. Also, I will advice you to keep your code nice, clean and short.

```
<?php
if($_POST){
  $inputName = $_POST['input_name'];
  $userId = $_POST['userid'];

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE benutzer SET username = :uname WHERE id = :id");
  $stmt-> bindValue(':uname', $inputName);
  $stmt-> bindValue(':id', $userId);
  $stmt-> execute();

  if($stmt){
    echo "User was successfully updated";
    header("Location: pannel.php");
    exit();
  }else{
    echo "Error updating the user";
  }
}

?>
```

And in your Form use the `onSubmit` for return confirm instead of PHP. This way you can confirm before reloading the page.

```
<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to upddate this user?')">
  <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $hiddenUserIdHere; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="input_name">
</form>
```

This is a better approach.

Comment: I tried your approach @RedStar Entertainment but when click yes to update I get this error: https://imgur.com/725OHd5 . The parameter / link of the page is this: http://192.168.178.30/modifyuser.php?modify=10

Comment: Please post your complete updated code (after using my code) so that I can spot the error. Or, mail your both PHP files (for that page given above and modifyuser.php only not the whole script) to jhajinamaste@gmail.com. Also, you do not need modifyuser.php which is an external page for processing the request unless you are using AJAX. Without AJAX you can do that on the same page. I will show you how. Mail me both the pages.